# Making the music play in the background after the app has been closed

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

My question here is about playing the music after the user closes the app (the app tab is not showing on the list of currently open apps).

I have created a class to handle the service that targets the media player to play the ring-tone music:

```
public class RingService extends Service {

private MediaPlayer player;


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this,
            Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
    player.setLooping(true);
    player.start();
    return START_STICKY;

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    player.stop();
}

}
```

in my MainActivity I use a button to start playing music. And it works fine till I close the app.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}


public void onRing(View view) {
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, RingService.class);
    startService(intent);

}

public void onStop(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RingService.class);
    stopService(intent);
}
}
```

Is there anyone who could tell me, what I'm doing wrong? I would be extremely grateful.
And just not to start another topic for this app, I will ask it here - is it possible to relaunch the activity in 10 seconds after it has been closed by the user?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the onCreate to implement

My app is doing good with this code:

```
public class BackgroundMusicService extends Service {
MediaPlayer musicPlayer;
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    musicPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.your_music_file);
    musicPlayer.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    musicPlayer.setVolume(100,100);

}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    musicPlayer.start();
    return 1;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    musicPlayer.stop();
    musicPlayer.release();
}
```

and in you manifest:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".BackgroundSoundService" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So after closing your app you want to play some ringtone using **RingService** but when user close the app the `onStop()` method is called in your MainActivity with this code `Intent intent = new Intent(this, RingService.class);
    stopService(intent);`. How service can play your music if you stopping your service at same time.
Try to delete this code from `onStop()` (not sure it will solve the problem but it worth trying).

Additionally I am recommending using Logcat for testing your code.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your service in foreground with `startForeground(id, notification)`, check the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground) for reference.

When you have a service in foreground, the chances of your process being killed are reduced drastically because your process won't be considered as in background. The downside is that you must show a permanent notification, which in your case might even be desirable because you might need controls for the player.